# Метод messages.send принимает параметр attachment

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, php-vksdk

В документации `vk.com/dev` говорится, что 
`метод messages.send принимает параметр attachment`, но непонятно, как передать в messages.send этот параметр? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Так же как и передаешь другие параметры(user_id,message) - если например передать фотографию, то в параметр attachment передаешь photo(id владельца)_(id картинки) - без скобок, если хочешь передать картинку с компьютера, то ее сначала нужно загрузить в вк, потом получить ее адрес, а потом его передавать в параметр attachment. Если хочешь передать несколько элементов, то просто перечисляеш их через запятую

Comment: if (msg.body == "чем вы занимаетесь?") msg.send("Отдыхаю", attachment photo photo510970512_456239094); бот здесь для бесед, может поможете с правильной формулировкой этой команды?

Answer (score 0):

Как делал я, без использование доп. библиотек

```
$request_params = array(
  'message' => $otwet,//Текст сообщения
  'user_id' => $userId,//Кому отправляем
  'access_token' => $token,//Токен
  'attachment' => 'photo(id владельца)_(id картинки)',//Адрес фотографии, без скобочек, например photo-47801984_456243139. Минус после "photo" означает, что владелец группа, если фотография находиться у пользователя, то без минуса
  'v' => '5.80',//Версия api
);

file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . http_build_query($request_params));//Отправляем сообщение
```